# Rest Template Builder Authorization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

How can I handle this request on server side in spring?

```
RestTemplate build = restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization(username, password).build();
ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = build.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

I mean, what is the difference if I just make a request and add the username and the password on the url "http: //...username={1}&password={2}" and on server side just make a controller and use @RequestParam anotations on methods ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to write your own authorization standards e.g. using custom request parameters. It makes it harder for the client to construct the request. By relying on known standards you make your server endpoints easier to understand, every developer should know what [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is.

Proposed approach with request parameters could be considered less secure comparing to header-based approach. Different frameworks and tools usually log the processed URL. Because of that there is a chance that username and password will be retained and exposed in the log files. Headers are generally not logged unless someone enables debug logs.

You can add Basic access authentication to your server with Spring Security [as show here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication).